# HBase connection hangs at INFO ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hbase, emr

I am trying to connect to HBase (version 0.94.18) on Hadoop (2.4) from my eclipse and connection hands after this. This happens on on my local machine only. 
code works fine on server.Any thoughts?

```
INFO  ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.dir=D:\eclipse\eclipse-jee-64\eclipse
INFO  ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=11.45.66.78:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
INFO  ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server ip-55-77-77-99.ec2.internal/11.45.66.78:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
INFO  ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to ip-55-77-77-99.ec2.internal/11.45.66.78:2181, initiating session
INFO  ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server ip-55-77-77-99.ec2.internal/11.45.66.78:2181, sessionid = 0x14b0dc1e5030dd7, negotiated timeout = 180000
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I should answer this question year and a half after question, but you should add all hostnames (if you use AWS add public and private DNS) from cluster to your local /etc/hosts file. I have this issue this week and this resolve my problem.